# Finding Monotonic Subsequence and Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find a monotonic subsequence of the sequence of $(x_n)$, where $(x_n)$ consists of all of the rational numbers in the interavl $[0,1]$ in some given order.

I know that every sequence contains a monotonic subsequence, but I'm not sure how to go about constructing it. Also, this sequence is bounded, so the monotonic subsequence must converge. How do I go about constructing such a sequence?

Comment: Hint: $(1 - \frac{1}{n}, 1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is infinite for $\forall n$.

Comment: If the order of your sequence is random , you can just copy the proof of "every sequence has a monotone subseequence" to this setup.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the order of the sequence that I'm given? For example, $x_n$ might be increasing, or it might be strictly decreasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider the subsequence $y_n$ of $x_n$ obtained from $x_n$ by removing $1$ and $0$.

We can find an increasing subsequence of $y_n$. We call an element $y_n$ special is $y_n\geq y_m$ for all $m\leq n$. Clearly the sequence of special elements is increasing.

We just have to prove there is an infinite number of special elements. To do this suppose that there is only a finite number of special elements, suppose $y_s$ is the last special element. Notice that there are rational numbers in the range $(y_s,1)$. The first element $y_n$ in this range must be special, a contradiction.  Therefore there is an infinite number of special elements, and the sequence $z_n$ of special elements works.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the order of $y_n$? Could you explain why it doesn't?

Comment: What if $(y_n)$ were strictly decreasing or increasing? Would it work then?

Comment: It's impossible for $(y_n)$ to be strictly decreasing.

Comment: @Mathematically, do you see why it is impossible for $x_n$ to be increasing? because there is an infinite number of rationals in the range $(x_1,x_2)$

Comment: I think I see. So what would the sequence converge to? I can't figure that out.

Comment: It's going to converge to $1$.

Comment: I see. If you had constructed it in the opposite fashion, it would have converged to zero, right?

Comment: Yup :D${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation.

Comment: you're 100% completely welcome @Mathematically